# What airfoil is used on the Lazair ultralight?

Tags: wing, airfoil, ultralight, lazair

[image: Airfoil]

This is the airfoil of the famous Lazair ultralight. What is the name of this airfoil?

Comment: Famous? I'd not heard of it before this.  Ah, I see why:  "sold in kit form between 1979 and 1984", so production stopped 10 years before I started flying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks close but I think there is too much camber in it as depicted above, and that is only the root airfoil.  There are significant changes along the span.

I used to jokingly call it my 'Lie Back' airfoil because I usually design things at night in bed :)

At some point I hope to get a 3D CAD model published of the whole Lazair series of aircraft but I can't promise when.

The Lazair is to be featured on a Canadian stamp this year and there is a Lazair in the Smithsonian :)

Dale Kramer

PS.  Peter Corley was killed in the Toucan of his own design and I never flew any aircraft with Peter hanging on my waist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Dale, and thank you for your answer! I hope you stick around!

Comment: Dale on Stack exchange?!?!.....wow,S.E keeps getting better.Welcome Sir.

Answer (score 4):

It's designer Dale Kramer's own home brew airfoil he developed mostly out of intuition and educated guessing. I don't know if he gave it a name.  I visited their kit factory and nearly bought a Lazair in 1979.

From [Lazairinfo.com](http://lazairinfo.com):

> Airfoil: Custom Lazair airfoil, reflexed top and bottom (said to be eyeballed by Dale Kramer)

Comment: The reason why am asking is 'cos the airfoil looks thick and the first series of lazair flew with 11hp meaning this airfoil is really efficient....

Comment: What was more impressive is I personally watched Dale take off with his business partner, Peter Corely, (later killed demoing at an airshow) hanging on behind the rear down tubes with his legs around Dale's waist.  The airplane wouldn't climb above about 30 feet but they completed a circuit of the field and plopped it down.  Peter was a reckless sort.

Comment: I think a downside to that airfoil is it was draggy enough to limit the airplane's L/D to about 10 which I think is low for a relatively clean design with a high aspect ratio.  I would've expected an L/D closer to 14 or 15.

Comment: Okay,I guess the airfoil wasn't as efficient as I thought... Wow u saw Dale and Peter demoing at an airshow...that means you're Canadian...(cool).....anyway...thank you for enlightening me on Lazairs airfoil.@John K

Comment: It was at the field near Welland, Ontario they flew from.  The factory was in town right beside the Welland Canal. Dale lives in NY State now.